# Darstellung von Umlauten in deutschen Tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Tags werden grundsätzlich in englischer Sprache angelegt ("Primärtags"). Ausnahmen sind die Tags *umlaut, eszett, kurrent, suetterlin*, was in der Natur dieser Begriffe liegt.  Der Tag *sein-or-haben* ist eine Mischung aus deutschen und englischen Bestandteilen. Die Tags *duden, heidegger* sind deutsche Eigennamen und nehmen eine Sonderrolle ein. Ich schlage die Löschung von *heidegger* vor (ist viel zu speziell).

Zu vielen Primärtags gibt es zusätzlich deutsche Synonyme. In einigen kommen Umlaute vor, die allerdings uneinheitlich wiedergegeben werden. Hier eine (hoffentlich) vollständige Liste:

zahlbarkeit
hoflichkeit
worterbucher
grazismus + graezismus
ubersetzung + uebersetzung
aufzaehlung
frageworter + fragewoerter
anfuehrungszeichen
falle [besonders schlecht, weil Fälle und Falle denkbare Interpretationen sind]
ausdrucke
suetterlin
prateritum
unzahlbar
grossschreibung

Meiner Meinung nach sollten die Umlaute **ä, ö, ü** grundsätzlich durch **ae, oe, ue** und nicht durch **a, o, u** dargestellt werden (ebenso wie ß durch ss ersetzt wird). Allerdings ergibt sich dadurch ein Problem mit der Suchfunktion: Die Umlaute werden intern durch **a, o, u** ersetzt. Z.B. findet man bei Eingabe von "Übersetzung" nur den Tag "ubersetzung" und nicht den Tag "uebersetzung".

Bei konsequenter Verwendung von **ae, oe, ue** müsste also dem Suchenden bekannt sein, dass er Umlaute dadurch zu ersetzen hat. Davon kann man leider nicht ausgehen.

Ein ähnliches Problem entsteht bei konsequenter Verwendung von **a, o, u**. Hier scheitert die Suche, falls der Suchende von sich aus Umlaute durch **ae, oe, ue** ersetzt.

Ich sehe daher nur zwei Lösungen:

1. Für jeden Tag mit Umlaut werden zwei Tags angelegt (wie bei *ubersetzung + uebersetzung*) und dem englischen Primärtag als Synoynm zugeordnet.
2. Für jeden Tag mit Umlaut wird ein Tag mit dem Schema  "uebersetzung-alias-ubersetzung" o.ä. angelegt.

Ich schlage Variante 2 vor.

Sichtbar sind die Alternativnamen der Tags nur bei den Vorschlägen, wenn die Nutzer sie eingeben:
[image: Tag-Vorschläge für 'Aufzah'(lung)]

Comment: Jetzt wäre es wichtig zu wissen, wie der Tag-Vorschlag-Algorithmus Umlaute behandelt, also: Wenn ich in einer Frage das Wort *unzählbar* schreibe, wird mir dann [unzahlbar] vorgeschlagen? Und was ist bei *unzaehlbar?* Kann man wahrscheinlich durch Meta-Recherche oder experimentell herausfinden …

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Guter Hinweis, ich habe das empirisch geprüft und werde einen Update der Frage machen.

Comment: Umgesetzt mit Variante 1. Bitte überprüfe einmal, dass ich nichts vergessen habe.

Comment: Mal ganz blöd gefragt: Warum kann man die deutschen Synonymen denn nicht korrekt mit Umlaut schrieben? Hat das einen technischen Grund? Wenn ja, würde ich einen Feature Request anregen. Wenn nicht, würde ich hingegen ganz heftig dafür plädieren, die Wörter doch ganz einfach **richtig** (also mit Umlaut und mit großem Anfangsbuchstaben) zu schreiben.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Alles in Ordnung! Vielen Dank für die Fleißarbeit.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Aktuell ist es unmöglich, Tags mit Umlauten oder Großbuchstaben anzulegen (https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). Wäre also   ein Feature Request. Ich vermute, dass es wenig Chancen für eine Umsetzung gibt, weil die Tag-Regeln auf allen Seiten von stackexchange identisch sein dürften.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich präferiere klar Variante 1 und sehe gerade nicht, welchen Vorteil Variante 2 bringen soll.

Zunächst einmal ist zu beachten, dass die betroffenen Tags nur für die Eingabemaske für neue Fragen bzw. beim Editieren relevant. In allen anderen Fällen sieht man nur das jeweilige Synonym und wir müssen uns nicht darum sorgen, eine falsche Schreibung zu propagieren.

Bei Variante 2 muss man sich erstmal durch ein Monster wie [anfuehrungszeichen-alias-anfuhrungszeichen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anfuehrungszeichen-alias-anfuhrungszeichen) lesen, was zweimal fast dasselbe Wort ist. Den Unterschied, der das *alias* erklärt, kann man leicht übersehen, was erstmal verwirrend ist. Letztlich sind Tag-Synonyme ja gerade dafür da, Aliase eben ohne komplizierte Konstruktionen zu implementieren.

Wer die richtige Schreibung des Wortes wissen möchte oder falls Unklarheiten bestehen, hat den Tag-Wiki-Exzerpt. Mir ist bewusst, dass viele diesen nicht beachten, aber ich bezweifle, dass bei denjenigen Variante 2 viel reißen wird, sondern eher die automatisch angebotenen Tags blind genutzt werden u. Ä.

Comment: Falls das Konsens ist: Kann ich bei der Umsetzung helfen?

Comment: @PaulFrost: Das hast Du schon getan, indem Du die Liste erstellt hast. Die meisten nötigen Aktionen sind nur für Moderatoren möglich oder bedeutend einfacher für Moderatoren. Außerdem können wir Tags umbenennen ohne die Hauptseite mit allen betroffenen Fragen zuzumüllen.

Answer (score 0):

Man sollte die Tags, die bei Weglassen des Umlautes bedeutungsverschieden verstanden werden IMHO gar nicht anlegen und anbieten. Das gilt insbesondere für von den oben genannten:

- Aufzählung ist nicht Aufzahlung
- Zählbarkeit ist nicht Zahlbarkeit
- unzählbar ist nicht unzahlbar
- Ausdrücke sind nicht Ausdrucke
- Fälle sind nicht Falle

in diesen fünf Fällen ist das Weglassen eine böse Falle. Weglasse des Umlaut ist keine Option und ein entsprechendes Anlegen des Tags wird nur Verwirrung stiften denn zur Klarheit gereichen. Sinngemäß muss das natürlich für weitere nicht genannte oder zukünftige synonyme Tags gelten.

Bei 'Fragewörtern' könnte man es sich einfach machen: im singular als Fragewort.
EDIT TO ADD: Das gleiche würde auch eindeutig und richtig für "Ausdruck" und "Fall" funktionieren.

Bei den restlich aufgeführten pellen mir sich zwar die Fußnägel beim einfachen Ersetzen der Umlaute durch die nicht-Umlaute, aber sie sind trotzdem eindeutig.

Mit obigen Einschränkungen: Lösung 1

Comment: "Fragewörter" zu "Fragewort" ist ein guter Vorschlag. Übrigens gibt es viele Tags sowohl im Plural als auch im Singular. Ich werde dazu eine neue Frage stellen.

Comment: tatsächlich funktioniert Singular auch eindeutig und richtig bei "Ausdruck" und "Fall".

Comment: Vgl. https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1682/34192

Comment: Bei diesen Wörtern liegt zwar in einem allgemeinen Kontext Mehrdeutigkeit vor, aber wenn es ums Taggen geht, sehe ich keine Probleme. Wenn ich nichts übersehen haben, ist der einzige Ort, wo man die falsche Schreibung überhaupt sieht, in der Tag-Auswahl beim Fragestellen in der Box des englischen Tags ganz unten in klein unter *also.* Ich kann leider keinen Screenshot davon machen (weil jeder Tastendruck die Box verschwinden lässt), aber wenn man [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) z. B. *aufz* in das Tag-Feld eingibt, sieht man es.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense (and I added this explanation in illustration to the question)